# Open PDF file inside Android app only works with unsigned APK on Android

Tags: java, android

I use the code below to open a PDF file and it works perfectly if I distribute the APK file unsigned.

Code: https://www.online-java.com/i5u7QPU9N4

But if I sign the APK that I created using my Android Studio, the app crash with the following message:

```
Caused by: ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
01-24 17:06:20.750 29758 29758 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
01-24 17:06:20.750 29758 29758 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(
```

Is it possible that something like Proguard was affecting the signed APK ? Or it can be other problem ?

EDIT

This is my app-level build.gradle file.

https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y2356950e

I have minifyEnabled, but it is declared false.

Comment: There is no such thing as running an unsigned APK-  Android won't run those.  Even debug APKs are signed, they're just signed by a key created by the IDE.  They're created only for users who want to separate the signing and compiling steps.

Comment: You are correct, the debug APK works perfectly. The APK that I sign with my own key is the one that didn't work properly.

Comment: What's in your app-level build.gradle, do you have minifyEnabled or something else interesting?

Comment: According to the error, you are not *opening* a PDF. You are *generating* one. You should debug to figure out why the generated document is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Proguard` could be one issue like you're speculating. It's hard to know based on the information you provided. But, here are things you can try;

1. Disable Proguard: You can disable Proguard in your build.gradle file by removing the following line: minifyEnabled true
2. Configure Proguard: You can configure Proguard to keep the necessary code or resources by adding specific rules in the proguard-rules.pro file. For example, to keep the iText library that you are using to open the PDF file, you can add the following rule: -keep class com.itextpdf.** { *; }
3. Check the PDF file: The error message "The document has no pages" suggests that the app is trying to open an empty or invalid PDF file. Make sure that the PDF file that you are trying to open is not empty and is not corrupted.
4. Check the Permission: Make sure you have "android.permission.INTERNET" in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
5. Check the PDF reader library: Make sure you are using the right version of iText library and it is compatible with your android version.

The summary is that it depends on the specifics of your app and the PDF file that you are trying to open.

Comment: If I use "minifyEnabled false", is Proguard will be disabled ?

Comment: Yes, use `minifyEnabled false` or remove that line. (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Answer (score 1):

Check below things may help.
1.INTERNET PERMISSION
2.check READ PERMISSION or add below code in manifest.

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```